# How do facetiles in Apple Photos that correspond to RKFace.modelId?

Tags: sqlite, cryptography, deep-learning, apple-photos

I have been digging through the Apple Photos macOS app for a couple weekends now and I am stuck. I am hoping the smart people at StackOverflow can figure this out.

What I don't know:

1. How are new hex directories determined and how do they correspond to RK.modelId. Perhaps 16 mod of RKFace.ModelId, or mod 256 of RKFace.ModelId?
2. After a while, the facetile hex value no longer corresponds to the RKFace.ModelId. For example RKFace.modelId 61047 should be facetile_ee77.jpeg. The correct facetile, however, is face/20/01/facetile_1209b.jpeg. hex value 1209b is dec value 73883 for which I have no RKFace.ModelId.

---

Things I know:

1. Apple Photos leverages deep learning networks to detect and crop faces out of your imported photos. It saves a cropped jpeg these detected faces into your photo library in resources/media/face/00/00/facetile_1.jpeg.
2. A record corresponding to this facetile is inserted into RKFace where RKFace.modelId integer is the decimal number of tail hex version of the filename. You can use a [standard dec to hex converter](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter) and derive the correct values. For example:
   [image: RKFace.modelId to facetile filename]
3. Each subdirectory, for example "/00/00" will only hold a maximum of 256 facetiles before it starts a new directory. The directory name is also in hex format with directories. For example 3e, 3f.

Answer (score 0):

While trying to render photo mosaics, I stumbled upon that issue, too...

Then I was lucky to find both a `master` image and the corresponding facetile, 
allowing me to grep around, searching for the decimal and hex equivalent of the numbers embedded in the filenames.

This is what I came up with (assuming you are searching for someone named `NAME`):

```
SELECT 
    printf('%04x', mr.modelId) AS tileId 
FROM 
    RKModelResource mr, RKFace f, RKPerson p 
WHERE 
    f.modelId = mr.attachedModelId 
    AND f.personId = p.modelId 
    AND p.displayName = NAME
```

This `select` prints out all `RKModelResource.modelIds` in hex, used to name the corresponding `facetiles` you were searching for. All that is needed now is the complete path to the facetile.

So, a complete `bash` script to copy all those facetiles of a person (to a local folder `out` in the current directory) could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eEu

PHOTOS_PATH=$HOME/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary
DB_PATH=$PHOTOS_PATH/database/photos.db

echo $NAME
mkdir -p out/$NAME

TILES=( $(sqlite3 "$DB_PATH" "SELECT printf('%04x', mr.modelId) AS tileId FROM RKModelResource mr, RKFace f, RKPerson p WHERE f.modelId = mr.attachedModelId AND f.personId = p.modelId AND p.displayName='"$NAME"'") )
for TILE in ${TILES[@]}; do
    FOLDER=${TILE:0:2}
    SOURCE="$PHOTOS_PATH/resources/media/face/$FOLDER/00/facetile_$TILE.jpeg"
    [[ -e "$SOURCE" ]] || continue
    TARGET=out/$NAME/$TILE.jpeg
    [[ -e "$TARGET" ]] && continue
    cp "$SOURCE" "$TARGET" || :
done
```